# php ! operator not working

Tags: php

I have this code for a few check-boxes, works fine like this

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $order_type) {
    if ('1' == $_POST[$key]) $_POST[$key] = '0';
}
```

if I negate the if it stops working and I'm sure that some are not == '1'; it just sets them to NULL.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $order_type) {
    if ('1' != $_POST[$key]) $_POST[$key] = '0';
}
```

do I miss anything ? tried with `!('1' == $_POST[$key])` too.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you not doing ('1' == $order_type) instead? Why use a foreach() loop to get key/val and not use val O.o

Comment: the main point is not about the functionality of the code is about why it works with == and why not with != .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes only get sent to the server if they are checked.

I assume that they have a value of `1`, so you will be able to find these in the `$_POST` array. However, there will be none where the value is `0` (unless you specify a value of `0` in the html and check the box...).

To check checkboxes, you need to use `isset` as the value is really not that important, it is either set (checked) or not and then it simply does not appear.

Comment: I see, the $_POST, is not even there. Thanks

Comment: You can put hidden field with value 0 and same name as checkbox just before the checkbox in HTML - then you'll get 0 value in post when checkbox is not checked.

Comment: @lupatus I guess that would work, but it is kind of an hack that I would rather not rely on.

Comment: you never can rely on input values and one should always check if value exists and if it is valid (as someone can fake request for example). anyway I think its a nice trick to set default values for checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple if/else?

```
if ('1' == $_POST[$key]) {
   $_POST[$key] = '0'; }
else {
   Do this if it's != ;
}
```

Comment: is not that I can't make it working is more like odd, and  I'm curious why.